# Error(Segmentation fault) while implementing method to find minimum value of Binary Tree in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

**I'm attaching my code at the end. I wrote this in C++**

I implemented a Binary 'search' Tree using custom classes Node and BinarySearchTree. Methods insert, find, all depth-first traversals are giving output as expected. Where as the **method to find height** of the tree gave **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** error if I **excluded** the code

```
if (root == nullptr)
        return -1;
```

But the expected behaviour is to give me the correct output (height of the tree), as the above code corresponds to a single edge case when the BinarysearchTree object(here 'tree') is empty.
If I included that particular code, the output is as expected, there are no errors.

Similarly, for the method to find **minimum of the tree** (I used implementation to find minimum of any Binary tree, not just Binary Search Tree on purpose), I get the same **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** error. When I tried to include above code (which I think is just an edge case), my output is the return value from that code('-1' here), if this return value is less than all values in my tree.

I need help with this, as I have no idea where I am going wrong.

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Node
{
public:
    int value;
    Node *leftChild;
    Node *rightChild;

    Node(int value)
    {
        this->value = value;
        leftChild = rightChild = nullptr;
    }
};

class BinarySearchTree
{
    Node *root;

    void traverseInOrder(Node *root)
    {
        if (root == nullptr)
            return;

        traverseInOrder(root->leftChild);
        std::cout << root->value << " ";
        traverseInOrder(root->rightChild);
    }

    int height(Node *root)
    {
        // if (root == nullptr)
        //     return -1;

        // checking if root is a leaf node
        if ((root->leftChild == nullptr) && (root->rightChild == nullptr))
            return 0;

        return (1 + std::max(height(root->leftChild), height(root->rightChild)));
    }

    int minimum(Node *root)
    {
        // if (root == nullptr)
        //     return -1;

        // checking if root is a leaf node
        if ((root->leftChild == nullptr) && (root->rightChild == nullptr))
            return root->value;
        return std::min({minimum(root->leftChild), minimum(root->rightChild), root->value});
    }

public:
    BinarySearchTree()
    {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    void insert(int value)
    {
        Node *node = new Node(value);
        if (root == nullptr)
        {
            root = node;
            return;
        }

        Node *current = root;
        while (1)
        {
            if (value < current->value)
            {
                if (current->leftChild == nullptr)
                {
                    current->leftChild = node;
                    return;
                }
                current = current->leftChild;
            }
            else
            {
                if (current->rightChild == nullptr)
                {
                    current->rightChild = node;
                    return;
                }
                current = current->rightChild;
            }
        }
    }

    bool find(int value)
    {
        Node *current = root;
        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            if (value < current->value)
                current = current->leftChild;
            else if (value > current->value)
                current = current->rightChild;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void traverseInOrder()
    {
        traverseInOrder(root);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    int height()
    {
        return height(root);
    }

    int minimum()
    {
        return minimum(root);
    }
};

int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree tree;

    tree.insert(12);
    tree.insert(16);
    tree.insert(4);
    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(25);
    tree.insert(3);
    tree.insert(30);
    tree.insert(23);

    tree.traverseInOrder();

    std::cout << tree.height() << std::endl;
    std::cout << tree.minimum() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the neutral term for addition is 0 not -1

Comment: Once it gets to the bottom, if there is a node with only one child (let's say left), what stops the recursive call from dereferencing a null pointer when called for the other nonexistent child (right)? Yep, it was the check for root==null.

Comment: When only one of the children, either left or right, is null, you are calling height on it recursively without check, so you need to check it the current node is null at the beginning of the method

Comment: Use small and systematic test cases so you can find out when the code breaks - this makes it easier to figure out why. If you test with a tree that has one node, it works. If the tree has two nodes, it breaks. Then think about what a tree with two nodes looks like (this is easy; there are only two possibilities) and how you're recursing through it (this is also easy since the tree is very small).

Comment: Create a small failing example and start debugging. (Works even with pen & paper)

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I appreciate @dratenik for pointing out precisely where I went wrong. That was helpful. I included cases for when nodes contain only left child or right child and it works like a charm.